# How can I get a list of AirPlay devices using CoreAudio

Tags: macos, core-audio

How can I get a list of available AirPlay devices using CoreAudio? Is it even possible? I can enumerate all of the connected devices, and list includes one "AirPlay" entry, but I have two devices and would like to select between them. How can I do this in MAcOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer here is to use the Bonjour API, not CoreAudio. AirPlay devices register themselves as such and have to be enumerated using Bonjour.

Answer (score 0):

I believe each AirPlay device is listed as a data source (`kAudioDevicePropertyDataSource`) under the AirPlay `AudioDeviceID`.

Comment: But the available devices are not enumerated. I haven't had a chance to look in to it, but I'm pretty sure I'll need to use the Bonjour API to get the available devices enumerated.